# how to display which product related price is increasing year by year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one doubt in SQL server. How to get which productname have price increaseing year by year.
in the below table apple product price is increase year by year so I need that records
if any product one year is high and another year price is drop then no need to get that records
if any product  one year price is 10 and next year price must be increast compare to prviouse then that record need to display

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product](
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [price] [money] NULL,
    [year] [int] NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[productdetails](
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [pname] [varchar](50) NULL
);

INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (1, 10.0000, 2010);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (1, 9.0000, 2011);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (1, 13.0000, 2012);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (2, 30.0000, 2010);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (2, 20.0000, 2011);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (2, 19.0000, 2012);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 8.0000, 2010);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 10.0000, 2011);
INSERT [dbo].[product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 15.0000, 2012);

INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (1, N'lg');
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (2, N'samsung');
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (3, N'apple');
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (4, N'mi');
```

Based on the above data I want output like below

```
+--------------+
| Productname  |
+--------------+
| Apple        |
+--------------+
```

I tried like below

```
SELECT *
FROM   product p
       JOIN product pd
         ON p.pid = pd.pid
            AND p.year = pd.year + 1
            AND p.price >= pd.price
```

Can you please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL server

Comment: Is there always data for 3 years?

Comment: more 2010 to 2019 years have , i given only 3 years

Comment: What if the 2013 apple value is 13? What would be the expected result then?
Apple values - 8, 10, 15, 13

Comment: It seems that  product  LG  has 2011 / 9.0000 and  2012 / 13.000 and should be included in the results?

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct pd.pname [Product Name]
from [dbo].[productdetails] pd inner join [dbo].[product] p
on p.pid = pd.pid
where not exists (
  select 1 from product t
  where t.pid = pd.pid and 
  t.price <= (select price from product where pid = t.pid and year = t.year - 1)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06485378ff7500360129178d89466649).
Results:

```
> | Product Name  |
> | :------------ |
> | apple         |
```

If there are not prices for every year but you want to apply the condition to the previous stored year, then use this:

```
select distinct pd.pname [Product Name]
from [dbo].[productdetails] pd inner join [dbo].[product] p
on p.pid = pd.pid
where not exists (
  select 1 from product t
  where t.pid = pd.pid and 
  t.price <= (select max(price) from product where pid = t.pid and year < t.year)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8ec68aaf78908d6ca56e90c00e0d6ef).

Answer (score 1):

Using `LAG()` and `HAVING` with `COUNT` = `SUM`, you can get the expected result.

The query is dynamic, no need to hard-code year or the count of occurrences.

```
SELECT Q.pname AS ProductName
FROM (
    SELECT PD.PID, PD.pname,
          CASE WHEN COALESCE(
                      LAG(PR.price) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.PID ORDER BY PR.[year])
                   , PR.price) <= PR.price THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PFlag
    FROM product PR
    JOIN productdetails PD ON PD.pid = PR.pid
) Q 
GROUP BY Q.pname
HAVING COUNT(Q.pname) = SUM(Q.PFlag)
```

OUTPUT:

```
+--------------+
| Productname  |
+--------------+
| apple        |
+--------------+
```

[**db<> fiddle for the same**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=485957b0257dbb391266ed1f74be1e72)

Answer (score 0):

If data always there for fixed year 2010,2011&2012 - this following script will work-

```
SELECT
PID
FROM [dbo].[product]
GROUP BY PID
HAVING 
SUM(CASE WHEN [YEAR] = '2011' THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END)> 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [YEAR] = '2010' THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END)
AND 
SUM(CASE WHEN [YEAR]= '2012' THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END)>
    SUM(CASE WHEN [YEAR] = '2011' THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is
(uncomment the p1 and p0 to see the details)

```
SELECT Distinct
    pd.pname as Product
  --,p0.*
  --,p1.*
FROM   gbaluproduct p0
JOIN   gbaluproduct p1
   ON  p0.pid    = p1.pid
   AND p0.year + 1   = p1.year 
   AND p0.price < p1.price 
Left Join gbaluproductdetails pd
   ON  p0.pid    = pd.pid
```

Results--

```
Product
apple
lg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query...
This works even if you have more 3 records of data per product.

```
SELECT Max(productdetails.pname) as ProductName
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Lag(price, 1) OVER (partition BY pid ORDER BY pid, year ) AS LagPrice,
               price AS CurrentPrice,
               Lead (price, 1) OVER (partition BY pid ORDER BY pid, year) AS LeadPrice
        FROM   product) t1
       INNER JOIN productdetails ON productdetails.pid = t1.pid
WHERE  lagprice IS NOT NULL AND leadprice IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY t1.pid
HAVING Max(CASE WHEN leadprice < currentprice OR lagprice > currentprice THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 1
```

Or use this query (Similar to [Arulkumar's query](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55984816/2)).

```
SELECT Max(productdetails.pname) AS ProductName
FROM   (SELECT pid,
               CASE WHEN Lead(price) OVER (partition BY pid ORDER BY pid, year) >= price THEN 0 ELSE 1
               END AS Decreased
        FROM   product) tmp
       INNER JOIN productdetails ON productdetails.pid = tmp.pid
GROUP  BY tmp.pid
HAVING Sum(tmp.Decreased) <= 1
```

Tables schema and sample data *(Added more sample data)*

```
CREATE TABLE [product](
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [price] [money] NULL,
    [year] [int] NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [productdetails](
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [pname] [varchar](50) NULL
);

INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (1, 10.0000, 2010);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (1, 9.0000, 2011);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (1, 13.0000, 2012);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (2, 30.0000, 2010);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (2, 20.0000, 2011);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (2, 19.0000, 2012);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 8.0000, 2010);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 10.0000, 2011);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 15.0000, 2012);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 20.0000, 2013);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (3, 15.0000, 2014);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (4, 5.0000, 2010);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (4, 10.0000, 2011);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (4, 15.0000, 2012);
INSERT [product] ([pid], [price], [year]) VALUES (4, 20.0000, 2013);

INSERT [productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (1, N'lg');
INSERT [productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (2, N'samsung');
INSERT [productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (3, N'apple');
INSERT [productdetails] ([pid], [pname]) VALUES (4, N'mi');
```

All Data

```
+------+----------+------+
| pid  |  price   | year |
+------+----------+------+
|   1  | 10.0000  | 2010 |
|   1  |  9.0000  | 2011 |
|   1  | 13.0000  | 2012 |
|   2  | 30.0000  | 2010 |
|   2  | 20.0000  | 2011 |
|   2  | 19.0000  | 2012 |
|   3  |  8.0000  | 2010 |
|   3  | 10.0000  | 2011 |
|   3  | 15.0000  | 2012 |
|   3  | 20.0000  | 2013 |
|   3  | 15.0000  | 2014 |
|   4  |  5.0000  | 2010 |
|   4  | 10.0000  | 2011 |
|   4  | 15.0000  | 2012 |
|   4  | 20.0000  | 2013 |
+------+----------+------+
```

Query Result

```
+-------------+
| ProductName |
+-------------+
| mi          |
+-------------+
```

Online Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c55c02790f1a6f99bb8d560ab8d3149b

---

<sup>Reference</sup>
<sup>- Arulkumar's query: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55984816/2</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly. You could take advantage of `COUNT()`, `LAG()`, and `SUM()`, and just divide your logic into :

1. Get the current and previous year's price
2. Count the total number of product's records (how many years are there for each product).
3. Compare the current year price with the last year price, and if the price for the current year is larger than last year then it's incremental (we give it 1) else (it's decreased) we give it 0.
4. Get the sum of the comparison, if it's equal to the total number of products (the count on #2) then this means the product has never decreased the price.

Example  :

```
 SELECT
    pname
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.pid
    ,   p.price
    ,   p.year
    ,   LAG(p.price) OVER(PARTITION BY p.pid ORDER BY p.year) prvPrice
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY p.pid) totalPid
    ,   pd.pname
    FROM product p
    JOIN productdetails pd ON pd.pid = p.pid
) D 
GROUP BY    
    pname
,   totalPid
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN price > ISNULL(prvPrice,0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = totalPid
```

So, apple appeared 3 times in product table (totalPid), this means we need the price to increment 3 times (once a year) to fulfill your requirement.

You can correct the conditional logic to fit your need, but I just want to share this simple example for the sake of simplicity.